# NSStatusItem is oversized and invisible unless clicked

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsstatusitem

I am working on an app using NSStatusItem.

I have two problems 1 is the icon is missing on a un-selected state,

[image]

However, when you click where the icon should be the app shows up but the area is large. The same size as the menu.

[image]

Here is how I am createing the NSStatusItem and menu.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    _statusItem = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength];
    _statusItem.title = @"";
    _statusItem.image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"bulb"];
    _statusItem.alternateImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"bulb-alt"];
    _statusItem.highlightMode = YES;


    NSMenu *menu = [[NSMenu alloc] init];
    [menu addItemWithTitle:@"About App" action:@selector(openAboutThisImage:) keyEquivalent:@""];
    [menu addItem:[NSMenuItem separatorItem]]; // A thin grey line
    [menu addItemWithTitle:@"Start at Login" action:@selector(startAtLogin:) keyEquivalent:@""];
    [menu addItem:[NSMenuItem separatorItem]]; // A thin grey line
    [menu addItemWithTitle:@"Quit App" action:@selector(terminate:) keyEquivalent:@""];
    _statusItem.menu = menu;

}
```

I have two sets of icons. One white and one black. Each set has two sizes 16x16 and 32x32 (@2x).

Icon sizes:

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

The white ones are the same size.

the Asset JSON for the BLACK icon

```
  {
  "images" : [
    {
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "filename" : "bulb.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "filename" : "bulb@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "scale" : "3x"
    }
  ],
  "info" : {
    "version" : 1,
    "author" : "xcode"
  }
}
```

and white icon

```
{
  "images" : [
    {
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "filename" : "bulb-alt.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "filename" : "bulb-alt@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "scale" : "3x"
    }
  ],
  "info" : {
    "version" : 1,
    "author" : "xcode"
  }
}
```

I am really at a loss as to what is happening. I have been using [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsstatusitem?language=objc) as reference. But I'm obviously missing something.

Any help?

Comment: Re-check the icon sizes.

Comment: Checked and updated question with screenshots. They are the sizes stated

Comment: Please check that your white 2x icon is actually 32x32 because from the screenshots it seems to me the size is different.

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions:

- As your icons are square create the status bar with `NSSquareStatusItemLength`
- Use template image:

  ```
  NSImage *image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"bulb"];
  image.template = YES;
  _statusItem.image = image;
  ```

  And delete the line to set the alternate image. The OS manages the normal/dark appearance.

Comment: Changing to `NSSquareStatusItemLength` fixed the width issue. What do you mean change bulb to bulgTemplate? Change the name of the icons? Asset files? or just the call to the image `[NSImage imageNamed:@"bulbTemplate"];`

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It's still easier, I updated the answer.

Comment: Hmmm now no icons show up in either Dark or Light mode.

Comment: Did you already renamed the images to `...Template`? If yes revert this. And read Sulthan's comment. I agree that the inverted images seem not to be 16x16 and 32x32.

Comment: No, the image is still named `bulb.png`

Comment: I forgot a template image must be black and white. No greyscale, no colors. If you need grayscales you cannot take advantage of the template pattern.

Comment: The image is black and transparent. Should the transparent parts be white?

Comment: No, they can also be transparent. Then try the other way, rename the **asset** with `bulbTemplate` (the `Template` suffix is crucial) change the name in `imageNamed...` and delete the line `image.template = YES;`

Comment: That's closer! There is just a white box now where the icon should go.